# Point and triangle

Tags: c++

Task - where point, inside the triangle or outside. I check on Heron's formula for small triangles, and for the large. Then compare their sum. Most likely a bug in the function "area".

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <math.h>

    using namespace std;

    struct point
    {
        int x;
        int y;
    };

    double length(point first, point second)
    {
        double katet1=second.x-first.x;
        double katet2=second.y-first.y;
        return(sqrt(katet1*katet1+katet2*katet2));
    }

    double area(point a, point b, point c)
    {
        double ab = length(a,b);
        double bc = length(b,c);
        double ca = length(c,a);
        double p =(ab+bc+ca)/2;
        double s = sqrt(p*(p-ab)*(p-bc)*(p-ca));
        return(s);
    }

    int main()
    {
        int num;
        cin>>num;
        int win=0;
        for(int i=0; i<num; i++)
        {
            point d,a,b,c;
            cin>>d.x>>d.y>>a.x>>a.y>>b.x>>b.y>>c.x>>c.y;
            double s1,s2,s3,s4;
            s1=area(d,a,b);
            s2=area(d,b,c);
            s3=area(d,a,c);
            s4=area(a,b,c);
            if((s1+s2+s3)==s4)
                        win++;
        }
        cout<<win;
        cin.get();
    }
```

Does not pass all tests. 
For example test 1 1 1 0 0 2 2 0 3 must return 1 but return 0.
Whats wrong?
Sorry my bad english.

Comment: You should be much more specific with what your program is doing unexpectedly.  I assume it's compiling and running without a crash.  What are some of your results versus expected results?

Comment: You're comparing computed floating point numbers for exact equality. That doesn't really work - use a tolerance threshold instead. Look up [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to compare double with operator==.
The calculations may differ, you need to use an epsilon value for a mistake margin:

```
const double Epsilon = 0.0001;
if (((s1+s2+s3) >= s4 - Epsilon) && ((s1+s2+s3) <= s4 + Epsilon))
{
}
```

Comment: `abs(s1 + s2 + s3 - s4) <= Epsilon`

Comment: If you're going down this road, why not `abs((s1+s2+s3)-s4)<Epsilon`

Comment: Because it's irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You should not expect `(s1+s2+s3) == s4` for `double/float` works fine in computer's world. Try:

```
abs(s1 + s2 + s3 - s4) < Epsilon
```

*where Epsilon is your desired precision, for example set it to `0.00001`, `0.01`, `1.0`, and even more than `10.0` based on your application.*

--

[*"What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19422-01/819-3693/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: It's a standard library macro from `<float.h>` that defines the difference between 1 and the smallest representable number greater than 1. (There's a version for `float` too, it's called `FLT_EPSILON`.)

Comment: @H2CO3: `DBL_EPSILON` would be far too small a tolerance, unless you're only dealing with values significantly smaller than one. You have to choose a tolerance that's good enough for the problem you're solving, and well within the precision of the type over the range you're interested in.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Do you think `DBL_EPSILON * max(a, b)` would work then, for example?

Comment: Its more C++-y way is [`std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/epsilon).

Comment: @H2CO3: That's a reasonable approximation of the likely error from a single operation, but probably still far too small to use as a tolerance. There's no universal answer; you have to understand the problem, and the calculation used to solve it, in order to calculate a reasonable tolerance.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Surely one has to understand the problem and the intrinsics of how errors are generated and how they accumulate. I was only trying to give, as you said, a better approximation, instead of the off-the-top-of-one's-head 0.01.

Comment: @H2CO3: Even more than `10.0` can be a good precision for real applications, imagine your program is calculating and comparing the results of two sensors for measuring area of an stadium's football field. In this case even 10.0cm difference is acceptable.